# Scrapy: difficulty outputting multiple rows, xPath issue?

Tags: python, scrapy, output, row, pipeline

I'm trying to get Scrapy to extract the author, date, and post from the forum https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1209137.0, and import it into my items.

My desired results are: (with extraneous html that I'll clean later)

author 1, date 1, post 1

author 2, date 2, post 2,

But instead I get:
author 1,2,3,4 date 1,2,3,4, post 1,2,3,4

I've searched around and read a few things on changing xPaths from absolute to relative, but I can't seem to get it working properly. I'm unsure if that's the root cause, or if I need to create a pipeline to transform the data?

*************UPDATE**********CODE ATTACHED*********************

```
class Bitorg(scrapy.Spider):
name = "bitorg"
allowed_domains = ["bitcointalk.org"]
start_urls = [
    "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1209137.0"
]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('..//html/body'):
        item = BitorgItem()
        item['author'] = sel.xpath('.//b/a[@title]').extract()
        item['date'] = sel.xpath('.//td[@valign="middle"]/div[@class="smalltext"]').extract()
        item['post'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="post"]').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your spider? How would we know what's wrong otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

While the `<table>`, `<tbody>` and `<tr>` elements don't have attributes that can easily be selected, there is a `<td>` for each post with a class of `poster_info`.

To get a list of all posts, select on the `<td>` and the move up the tree using the xpath `..` notation.

```
posts = response.xpath('//*[@class="poster_info"]/..')
```

Within each post, select the child elements of interest.

```
for post in posts:
    author = ''.join(post.xpath('.//td[@class="poster_info"]/.//b/a/.//text()').extract())
    title = ''.join(post.xpath('.//div[@class="subject"]/.//a/.//text()').extract())
    date = ''.join(post.xpath('.//div[@class="subject"]/following-sibling::div/.//text()').extract())

    print '%s, %s, %s' % (author, title, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You know all that code is just one big div with a small tables insides 
and xpaths for authors

```
/html/body/div[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/b/a
/html/body/div[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/b/a
/html/body/div[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[6]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/b/a
```

you can use this so that you can scrape anything

```
l = XPathItemLoader(item = JustDialItem(),response = response)
for i in range(1,10):
        l.add_xpath('content1','//*[@id="bodyarea"]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/b/a/text()')
        l.add_xpath('content2','//*[@id="bodyarea"]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/b/a/text()')
        l.add_xpath('content3','//*[@id="bodyarea"]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/b/a/text()')
```

same way you can do also for date and post